# word for temporarily ordering a worker to a new position because of an emergency

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, transferring doctors from their specific departments to infectious diseases, where they have no specific knowledge or experience, because there is a pandemic. Transferring a graphic designer to the shop floor because of a product recall incident.

Similar verbs that come to mind are mostly used in the military:  '[commandeered](https://www.lexico.com/definition/commandeer)', usually applied to things (e.g. ships or buildings), and 'drafted' or 'conscripted'.

Comment: "Temporary reassignment".

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence showing how the target language is to be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While a hypernym,

**second** in one of its senses is usually the result of a perceived need:

> Definition of *second* (Entry 5 of 5) [transitive verb] ...
>
> 3\ si-​ˈkänd  \ [OALD has /sɪˈkɑːnd/] chiefly British:
>
> to release (someone, such as a
> military officer) from a regularly assigned position for temporary
> duty with another unit or organization

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second)]

An example from [Deloitte](http://newsletters.usdbriefs.com/2017/Tax/WTA/170623_6.pdf) [2017]:

> - *In 2008, a UK retailer (UK Co) set up an Indian joint venture company (JV Co) with a large Indian retailer, with a view to expanding
>   the presence of the UK company in India. JV Co thereafter concluded an
>   agreement with UK Co, under which several UK Co employees were
>   seconded to India to help set up the Indian business.*

And a COVID-related example from [BMJ Emergency Medicine Journal](https://emj.bmj.com/content/37/7/407):

> *To ensure adequate manpower, leave was embargoed and doctors from other departments were seconded to DEM.*

Comment: Yes, and such a tour of duty would be a *secondment*. The stress in this use is on the second syllable, not the first as in 'minutes and seconds'. In the US military, the common term is TDY (answer below).

Comment: Jim Mack: I noticed the shift in syllable stress too upon looking up the word. Interesting, though I wonder what difference does it make at all.

Comment: Defs British to my ear but good answer

Comment: Azor: British _but_ good?

Comment: *Second* does not include the connotation of an emergency situation. Secondments can be routine.

Comment: also notice the strange pronunciation - unlike second place or the second hand of a clock, the emphasis is on "cond"

Comment: ... which is why I (1) said that this was, while being a sound choice as shown in the examples,  a _hypernym_) and (2) (for the first time in a SWR answer) added the pronunciation/s.

Answer (score 10):

An emergency reassignment would be called a redeployment. Although military in origin, it is also used generally:

> re·de·ploy or reassign temporarily)

v. re·de·ployed, re·de·ploy·ing, re·de·ploys

v.tr.

1. To deploy (personnel, especially military forces) to a different place or on a different assignment.
2. To put to a different use or action; deploy in a different way: redeploy the company's resources.

v.intr.
To be deployed to a different area or assignment.

AHD https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=redeploy

Comment: The downside of "redeploy" is that it doesn't inherently carry the meaning of a *temporary* posting

Comment: @ChrisH I agree, but that’s the trouble with SWRs.

Answer (score 2):

The US military has an acronym (no surprise) for exactly this situation: ***[TDY](https://www.operationmilitarykids.org/military-tdy/)***, short for Temporary Duty. I regularly worked with people on TDY to our base for training or support. It sounds like a good analog to what you describe.

Unfortunately, while anyone who's had military experience will get it right away, no one else will unless you manage to spread it. (-:

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[assign](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/assign)*** may work in your case:

> If someone is assigned to a particular place, group, or person, they are sent there, usually in order to work at that place or for that person.

> - I was assigned to Troop A of the 10th Cavalry.

(Collins Dictionary)

From:
Seventeen Minus Two
by Virginia Phlieger-Kroos

> Our sisters were first sent there in 1956. Many of the young sisters hoped to serve there. Sister Mary Charity ( Celine) asked the Mother Superior to be assigned to the African Mission and was refused. ***Instead she was assigned to a smaller hospital.***

Answer (score 0):

**Allocate**

> to apportion for a specific purpose or to particular persons or things

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allocate)]

**Reallocate**

> to apportion or distribute (something) in a new or different way

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reallocate)]

**Transfer**

> to move to a different place, region, or situation

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer)]

Answer (score 0):

**interim**

It is possible to prepend the word **interim** to the position, as in this example from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interim):

> You are interim manager until he returns from hospital.

The word is defined in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interim):

> an intervening time interval